# Complex even and odd polynomials with real coefficients sharing a zero

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

It's true that if an $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an **odd polynomial**  and $g:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an **even polynomial** are polynomials with reals coeficients and they share a root, then that zero must have a positive real part ?

I was wondering about that and have a feeling that I have done a mistake

first: for a very higher degree polynomials they must share a root

if $z = re^i\theta$ is root of $g$, then let's calculate $g(3z)$.

So $$g(3e^{i\theta})  = (3r)^n( \frac{a_n}{(3r)^n}e^{ni\theta} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{(3r)^{n-1}}e^{(n-1)i\theta} + \ldots )$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$(3r)^n\|( \frac{a_n}{(3r)^n}e^{ni\theta} + \frac{a_{n-1}}{(3r)^{n-1}}e^{(n-1)i\theta} + \ldots)\| \leq (3r)^n \|\frac{a_n}{(3r)^n}e^{ni\theta}\| + \|\frac{a_{n-1}}{(3r)^{n-1}}e^{(n-1)i\theta}\| + \ldots 
$$$$\leq\|a_n\|+\|a_{n-1}\| + \|a_{n-2}\|\ldots $$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\|g(3e^{i\theta})\| \leq (3r)^n\|g(e^{i\theta})\| $$

We can exchange $3$ for any real number $l$, so looks like, for very big polynomial , the  root lies somewhere near another root if we take $0<l<1/r$ . Since $\|e^{i\theta}\|=\|e^{-i\theta}\| = \|- e^{i\theta}\|$, appears to have a high chance that, for very large degree, an **odd polynomial** share a root with an **even polynomial** and the whole thing looks like being converge to real line

Looks too good to be true

Comment: No.  If $r$ is a root of an even or odd polynomial, then so is $-r$.

Comment: $-1$ is a root of the even polynomial $x^2-1$ and of the odd polynomial $x^3 - x$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thx for the sharp counterexample ! About r being a root then $-r$ being too ... is it true for any $r$ ?

Comment: Yes.  For an even polynomial, $p(-r) = p(r) = 0$.  For an odd polynomial, $p(-r) = -p(r) = 0$.